# Unzip error in my code

Tags: zlib, unzip

I am designing a zip-unzip utility. I am using the **zlib** library. **Inflate** and **deflate** work perfectly without any errors. Unzip works alright for text and .c files but when I use it to compress **.mp3** or **.jpg** images the output size is **5B**. The pointers are perfect, I have verified that. What could be the reason for this error? Has anyone faced a similar problem? Can someone please guide me? I have been stuck here for quite some time.

Comment: Please include more information.  For example, add a small example program with the method you're having problems with.

Answer (score 0):

Check any additional return codes of the library.

A 5 byte block is a clear indicator, that there's nothing to compress. That kind of block consists of one byte code stating that the next block is "raw", two byte sequence telling the size of the next block and another two bytes that are bit inversion of the first length field. I believe the caller is supposed to write the next raw data block before calling deflate again.

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean by the return codes of library? I am a fresher.

Comment: If a library is even slightly complex there's always a possibility of failure. Instead of just returning null pointer, or corrupted buffer, a well written library sets at least a global variable to contain a documented "return_value" (e.g. enum { OK=0, OUT_OF_MEMORY=1, INVALID_STREAM=2 } ) etc. Because compression is not guaranteed to happen, there's a very good chance and a very good reason for zlib to somehow tell how the 5-byte result should be interpreted.

Comment: Fine, thanks! Let me check if I can find something. Its quite complex!